# Is there a workaround for the confirm popup bug in Firefox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox

Currently when I use the following Ruby on Rails code:
`= link_to "Confirm", user, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, :class => "button"`
This produces:
`<a class="button" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/users/2">Confirm</a>`

When I click on this button in Firefox (v8 Mac) the confirm pops up but it doesn't wait for the end user to click on the Yes or Cancel buttons and it automatically confirms. In the case that I have, it deletes the user.

This does not happen in Chrome.

Is there a workaround for this bug or should I be coding it differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem about a year ago. There was a bug in JQuery. Make sure you have the latest JQuery gem installed. It was in Firefox under Windows, however.